# Need to get the xpath for tags in the below xml

Tags: xml, xpath, jmeter, extractor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OutputParameters xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/sp/SearchBPDBService" xmlns:jca="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/wsdl/jca/" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Service" xmlns:plt="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/link/" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Service" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
   <ns0:X_B_P_INFO>
      <ns0:X_B_P_INFO_ITEM>
         <ns0:P_ID>147392640</ns0:P_ID>
         <ns0:F_ID>213910194</ns0:F_ID>
         <ns0:STATUS />
         <ns0:OS>
            <ns0:OS_ITEM>
               <ns0:O_P_ID>378602</ns0:O_P_ID>
               <ns0:F_ID>2937983</ns0:F_ID>
               <ns0:N_ID>614000751</ns0:N_ID>
               <ns0:O_MSET>
                  <ns0:O_MSET_ITEM>
                     <ns0:MSET>O-B-C1</ns0:MSET>
                     <ns0:PRIMARY_FLAG>true</ns0:PRIMARY_FLAG>
                  </ns0:O_MSET_ITEM>
               </ns0:O_MSET>
               <ns0:AgS>
                  <ns0:AgS_ITEM>
                     <ns0:Ag_P_ID>2088905</ns0:Ag_P_ID>
                     <ns0:F_ID>213910197</ns0:F_ID>
                     <ns0:NAR_ID>614005892</ns0:NAR_ID>
                     <ns0:Ag_MSET>
                        <ns0:Ag_MSET_ITEM>
                           <ns0:MSET>A-BCNJ-12091</ns0:MSET>
                           <ns0:PRIMARY_FLAG>true</ns0:PRIMARY_FLAG>
                        </ns0:Ag_MSET_ITEM>
                     </ns0:Ag_MSET>
                  </ns0:AgS_ITEM>
               </ns0:AgS>
            </ns0:OS_ITEM>
         </ns0:OS>
      </ns0:X_B_P_INFO_ITEM>
   </ns0:X_B_P_INFO>
</OutputParameters>
```

Tried both the below.
E.g.1 
//ns0:X_B_P_INFO/ns0:X_B_P_INFO_ITEM/ns0:P_ID

//ns0:X_B_P_INFO/ns0:X_B_P_INFO_ITEM/ns0:P_ID/ns0:OS/ns0:OS_ITEM/ns0:O_P_ID

//OutputParameters/[@ns0='X_B_P_INFO'/[@ns0='X_B_P_INFO_ITEM'/[@ns0='P_ID']/text()

//OutputParameters/ns0:X_B_P_INFO/ns0:X_B_P_INFO_ITEM/ns0:OFFICE_PARTY_ID/*

E.g.2 
//*[@id="collapsible0"]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]

I apologize in advance if this is a repeat, but am stumped with this, And Thank you.

Comment: @kjhughes - This format  <ns0:P_ID> with multiple /root references has not been asked before

Comment: Your "<ns0:P_ID> with multiple /root references" comment is unclear. XML cannot have multiple root elements, and there's nothing special about your format that's not covered in the duplicate links. Please read the entire answers; you should find that they answer your question.